# How to take back resizing of VM instance on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I resized VM instance on Google Cloud Platform and now it is displayed wrongly, custom styling is gone, products are gone - how I can revert it to the state before resizing?

Comment: Your question has no details. Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just want to revert VM to the state before resizing

Comment: I don't know what other details are important

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a snapshot or image of your original VM,

1. Create a new instance from your [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) or [image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage).
2. Keep the same size of the disk same as of the original VM.